# Is there a way to let Rails push an internal repository to Github while its hosted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Assume that I have a Rails project. I have published it on  a server like Heroku. Think of it as a small app that have to update a git repository (a separate repository in its public folder). Is there a way to achieve this?

For example...

Think that i have some markdown files in my public folder. My rails app will give me an interface to edit these files. When the editing is over, I need to push these files to a git repository. Only that folder through a script in the Rails app.

Comment: Please explain why you are really trying to achieve.  Not the how but the way and when.  It isn't clear from the question what your actual objective is.  Other than than "yes any files and directories including .git that you add and commit.

Comment: You can call out to a shell by using back ticks (`\``) and a few variations, but you'll probably have issues trying to do what you want to do on Heroku, which doesn't have any persistent disk – or at least, persistency isn't guaranteed beyond, I think, a single request.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical and imaginary problem, or a real situation? If it's real, give us real, situational, information so we can actually help you, instead of hypothetically helping.

Comment: I added a small example. Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either shell out to git:

```
Dir.chdir('/path/to/git/tree') do
  system = "git commit -m'Updated by rails' -- #{name_of_file_to_commit}"
  # Check $?, and do some appropriate error handling if it's != 0
end
```

Or you can use one of the several ruby Gems for interfacing with git.  I am not familiar enough with them to recommend one; in any case, any recommendation will soon be out of date.  It's best to do your own search, find candidate gems, and try them.